# Vb.net How to programically select the last tab in a tabcontrol

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, browser, tabcontrol, tab-ordering

I am making a Web Browser that has a TabControl and I can everything to work but when I click New Tab Button it creates a new tab with a web browser in it but I have to manually select that new tab to change the address. I want it so that when I click New Tab it redirects me automatically to the new tab not the current tab I was on. I have looked at "SelectedIndex" but that doesn't seem the best way to change the selected tab.

***In Summmary When I click New Tab it...***

1. Creates a new tab at the END of the tab control with the url set to about:blank
2. Doesn't change the selected tab to the "newly created tab"

Here is the code of the New Tab button

```
Private Sub btn_NewTab_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_NewTab.Click
    AddTab("about:blank", TabControl1) 
End Sub
```

The AddTab Sub code is below

```
Public Sub AddTab(ByRef URL As String, ByRef TabControl As TabControl)
    Dim NewBrowser As New CustomBrowser
    Dim NewTab As New TabPage
    NewBrowser.Tag = NewTab
    NewTab.Tag = NewBrowser
    TabControl.TabPages.Add(NewTab)
    NewTab.Controls.Add(NewBrowser)
    NewBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    NewBrowser.Navigate(URL)

End Sub
```

If you need to look at more of the code then he is a link to all of the code behind the web browser
[Full Code](http://lobsterproductions.weebly.com/uploads/1/9/5/1/1951779/tabbed_webbrowser.txt)

Update: I Have tried adding

> TabControl.SelectedIndex = TabControl.TabPages.Count - 1

to the AddTab sub and I get an error that highlights

> Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As
> EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
> Dim WB As CustomBrowser = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
> Me.cbURL.Text = WB.Url.ToString
>
> ```
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: What means that `SelectedIndex` _"doesn't seem to be the best way"?_

Comment: SelectedIndex - You have to assign an interger to each tab. Since I don't know how many tabs the user is creating it doesn't seem the best answer (Plus I don't fully understand it). In Summary all I want the add tab button to do is to create a new tab and to select that tab.

Comment: No, see my answer below where i show how you select the last tab. You don't need to assign an integer, `SelectedIndex` starts with 0 and ends with `tabControl.TabPages.Count-1`.

Comment: As per Tim's answer, you don't have to know how many tabs there are . TabControl object hold a .Count for their children.

Comment: Yes, but all I want it to do is to select the last tab in the tab control which is the newly created tab.

Comment: Tim I getting the error Property 'Count' is 'ReadOnly'

Comment: @NevilleSoftware: i have not modified the property above. I just wanted to show you the range of valid indexes. See my answer below where i show two ways to set the last tab as selected tab. The first is using  `TabControl.TabPages.SelectedIndex=TabControl.TabPages.Count-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't wknow what was wrong with `TabControl.SelectedIndex=TabControl.TabPages.Count-1`, but you could also use [`TabControl.SelectTab`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selecttab(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Public Sub AddTab(ByRef URL As String, ByRef TabControl As TabControl)
    Dim NewBrowser As New CustomBrowser
    Dim NewTab As New TabPage
    NewBrowser.Tag = NewTab
    NewTab.Tag = NewBrowser
    TabControl.TabPages.Add(NewTab)
    NewTab.Controls.Add(NewBrowser)
    NewBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    NewBrowser.Navigate(URL)

    TabControl.SelectTab(NewTab)
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry Wrong Error - I am getting another error which is An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Neville Net.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. It is also highlighting some of my code which is 'Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim WB As CustomBrowser = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
        Me.cbURL.Text = WB.Url.ToString


    End Sub'

Comment: What is `Nothing`, `Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab` or `Me.cbURL` or `WB` or `WB.Url`? Use the debugger.

Comment: Sorry about that, cbURL is a Combo box which is the address bar. WB is the Custom Web Browser so that would mean WB is a web browser and WB.Url is the web browsers current url. To understand the code a bit more here is a link to the source code [Source Code](http://lobsterproductions.weebly.com/uploads/1/9/5/1/1951779/tabbed_webbrowser.txt)

Comment: @NevilleSoftware: you haven't mentioned what exactly is `Nothing`.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing" are you talking about the additional spacing in my code, I sometimes add spacing because I might place code there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TabControl.SelectTab` method and set the selected tab to any one you want. More details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
        Dim i As Integer
        i = yourForm.TabControl.TabPages.Count
        yourForm.TabControl.SelectedIndex = i - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I use

`Private Sub Add_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Add.Click   Dim t As New TabPage                                                              Dim newtab As New tab_layout                                            newtab.Show()                                  newtab.AxWebBrowser1.RegisterAsBrowser = True                          newtab.Visible = True                                                 newtab.TopLevel = False                                                   newtab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill                                   t.Controls.Add(newtab)                            Browser.TabControl1.TabPages.Add(t)                   Browser.TabControl1.SelectedTab = t                                                   End Sub`

and

`Private Sub tab_layout_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load                          AxWebBrowser1.Navigate(My.Settings.Home)                                              End Sub`

for the problems you have

maybe this will help you

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be helpful to tidy up the formatting in the code block.

Answer (score 0):

The question states that using SelectedIndex does not work, and the majority of answers thus far suggest selecting a TabPage by name using SelectTab(nawtabpage) for a TabPage that was just created.  However, when you need to select a TabPage which already exists, from anywhere in e.g. Form1 (the TabControl is on Form1), you can use the following command:

```
   TabControl1.TabPages(0).Select()
```

where `(0)` is TabPage 0 in TabControl1.  If there are 4 TabPages in TabControl1, then their indices are 0,1,2,3, so selecting the last tab in the control (like the question asks) is just a variation on a theme, i.e.:

```
   TabControl1.TabPages(3).Select()
```

Comment: Consider editing your answer to to include an explanation of your code and how it addresses the problem/question? That will help future readers better understand what is going on. When there are existing and accepted answers, it helps to explain how your answer differs from or improves on the others.